# CountDownTimer, ViewPager, Ad and constant refreshing ListView items - strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, ads, countdowntimer

I'm using ViewPager and the ad (from Admob) in layout xml.
I have two fragments (HomeFragment and TeamFragment), one has a CountDownTimer and the other has a ListView. As we know, ViewPager keeps both with created views so both are active at the same time.

The problem is that: **When my CountDonwTimer ticks (onTick is called), items (rows) from ListView are refreshed (getView() from ListAdapter are called).**

What is interesting, it only occurs when the ad shows (Internet connection is on). When there is no ad, everythings works ok (no refresh from ListView).

This is not a big problem, but it drains battery.

Logs:

```
01-21 15:56:35.150: D/HomeFragment(17366): onTick() in CountDownTimer - just before counterTV.setText(...)
01-21 15:56:35.155: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:35.215: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:35.230: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:35.245: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:35.255: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
01-21 15:56:35.260: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:35.265: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:35.265: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:35.270: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:35.275: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
01-21 15:56:40.160: D/HomeFragment(17366): onTick() in CountDownTimer - just before counterTV.setText(...)
01-21 15:56:40.170: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:40.185: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:40.200: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:40.215: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:40.225: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
01-21 15:56:40.245: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:40.260: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:40.260: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:40.265: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:40.270: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
01-21 15:56:45.165: D/HomeFragment(17366): onTick() in CountDownTimer - just before counterTV.setText(...)
01-21 15:56:45.170: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:45.185: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:45.200: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:45.215: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:45.225: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
01-21 15:56:45.245: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 0
01-21 15:56:45.260: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 1
01-21 15:56:45.265: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 2
01-21 15:56:45.270: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 3
01-21 15:56:45.270: D/ListAdapter in TeamFragment(17366): getView() position: 4
```

HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    (...)

    private OpeningCeremonyTimer countDownTimer;
    private TextView counterTV;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (...)

        countDownTimer = new OpeningCeremonyTimer(initialTime, 5000);
        countDownTimer.start();

        return view;
    }

    private class OpeningCeremonyTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        private StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

        public OpeningCeremonyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setLength(0);
            if (millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                long count = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
                if (count > 1)
                    time.append(count).append(" days ");
                else
                    time.append(count).append(" day ");
                millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
            }

            time.append(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));

            Log.d(TAG, "onTick() in CountDownTimer - just before counterTV.setText(...)");
            counterTV.setText(time.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            counterTV.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));

        }

    }
}
```

TeamFragment:

```
public class TeamFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    (...)


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (...)

        TeamFragmentListAdapter matchesListAdapter = new TeamFragmentListAdapter(context, matchesList);
        matchesLV.setAdapter(matchesListAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Here is my main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
I just changed layout_height="wrap_content" to layout_height="match_parent" in my ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/groupsLV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
</ListView>
```

More info about wrap_conent and match_parent in ListViews is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70